# Merge list of maps into a single map by summing values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class Values:

```
public class Values {
    private int count;
    private int values;
}
```

And a list of multiple maps of type `Map<String, Values>`

```
Map<String, Values> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1 .put("aaa", new Values(1, 10));
        map1 .put("bbb", new Values(5, 50));
        map1 .put("ccc", new Values(2, 30));

Map<String, Values> map2= new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("aaa", new Values(2, 20));
        map2.put("bbb", new Values(3, 50));
        map2.put("ccc", new Values(3, 10));

List<Map<String, Values>> list = Arrays.asList(map1, map2);
```

There could be any number of maps and any number of entries inside the maps, but the keys for the maps are always the same, only the values can differ. My example contains only 2 maps and only 3 entries for each map for clarity.

I want to obtain a single map with the same keys and with the Values objects as the sum of each "count" and each "value" in the objects, like this:

```
{
        aaa= {
            count = 3,
            value = 30
        },
        bbb= {
            count = 8,
            value = 100
        },
        ccc= {
            count = 6,
            value = 40
        }
    }
```

I am trying to achieve this using the Streams API, but I am stuck:

```
public static Map<String, Values> mergeMaps(List<Map<String, Values>> maps) {
        return maps.stream()
                .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()) ...?
    }
```

How can I group each entry by their keys and add up each count and each value into a single map?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can collect the entries of your `Stream` with a `toMap` collector, with a merge function.

```
public static Map<String, Values> mergeMaps(List<Map<String, Values>> maps) {
    return maps.stream()
               .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                         Map.Entry::getValue,
                                         (v1,v2) -> new Values(v1,v2)));
}
```

Assuming you have a `Values` constructor that takes two `Values` instances and creates an instance having the sums of the values.

Of course, you can write the merge function without that constructor. For example:

```
(v1,v2) -> new Values(v1.getCount()+v2.getCount(),v1.getValue()+v2.getValue())
```

Comment: Regarding the constructor that two `Values` to represent `(v1,v2) -> new Values(v1,v2)`, I doubt how good a choice of having such a constructor be. Given if that really exists, calling `Values::new` would rather be clean. Though using a static method to add these attributes and return back a `Value` shall be a better choice in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

One more solution with groupingBy:

```
Map<String, Optional<Values>> collect = list.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                    reducing((v1, v2) -> new Values(v1.count + v2.count, v1.values + v2.values)))));
```

Note: values of this map are `Optional<Values>`. 
If you have `null` value on one of your source map like `map2.put("ddd", null);`
it allows to avoid `NullPointerException` and return `Optional.empty`